# ActiveRecord order by array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

If I have an array such as: `['Apple','Orange','Pear']`

How could I retrieve records from a model by implementing a "custom sort"? For example, what if I want to sort the `fruit_type` column by `Orange`, `Pear`, and then `Apple`?

Not trying to sort alphabetically or numerically, but just based on a custom order that I'm looking for.

Comment: You have a two options, 1. Custom indexing(position) like `Eyeslandic` mentioned, or 2. Custom algorithm ))

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think would be to create a new table with something like

```
create_table :fruit_types do |t|
  t.string  :name
  t.integer :sort_order
  # .....
end
```

Then use that in your model

```
# model.rb
belongs_to :fruit_type
```

Then query with

```
Model.joins(:fruit_type).order('fruit_types.sort_order')
```